# SignalR namespace conflict? Can't use MapHubs()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0, signalr

Trying to update signalr libs in my project, and suddenly solution doesn't build.

I have references to these guys:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb.dll
```

I have this in global.asax:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;
```

Intellisense sees that RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs() comes from SignalRRouteExtensions, but still breaks the build. Project is .net 4.0 MVC 3 app. Should not have any problems.

Do you guys have any ideas why this is happening?

```
Error 71 'System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection' does not contain a definition for 'MapHubs' and no extension method 'MapHubs' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    Global.asax.cs
```

Comment: What's the error message that you're seeing?

Comment: I updated the question with the error message

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your error, just created a fresh MVC3 and did everything you mentioned.  Try re-building, if that doesn't work could you post a simple reproduction project?

Comment: I don't know why it's not working. I tried to convert it to 4.5 and it worked. My admins though can't let me do that yet. So I have to find out why it's not building. Maybe because I'm using VS update 2 CTP. I don't know

Comment: I hope, you will got the solution here.. http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/upgrading-signalr-1x-projects-to-20 Try..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you manually reference the SignalR dll's instead of installing via NuGet? If so, I would suggest making sure your `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb.dll` is targeted to .NET 4.0 instead of 4.5. SignalR provides different versions of that assembly.

You can use Reflector or ildasm to help you with this. Just look at the assembly's `TargetFrameworkAttribute::.ctor(string)` in the Manifest and make sure it contains ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".

Comment: yeah probably that's it... I got the libraries via nuget through a project that 4.5 and manually hook'em on the 4.0 project... lame job. my bad

Comment: I just tried to get 4.0 SignalR assemblies, cleaned the solution, tried to rebuild it - still won't work... :( Both core and SystemWeb show target framework as 4.0

Comment: That's very very strange... I converted the project to 4.5. Built. Converted it back to 4.0. Rebuilt and it builds now... Shhhtrange

Answer (score 2):

Also i found that when using the unstable 2.0.0-beta releases this happened. when downgrading to 1.1.3 then it worked fine.